# how to close a RadContextMenu manually

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am trying to use the `ItemMouseLeave` and `ItemMouseEnter` events of a `RadListView` in order to add and remove items from a `RadContextMenu`, however I noticed that it dynamically adds items to the context menu even while it is open. Which is something I did not want. So I created a bool variable to keep track of its open and closed state with the `DropDownClosed` and `DropDownOpened` events of the context menu. This also did not work, because if you right click outside of an item and then right click on an item while the context menu is already open it seems the context menu does not actually close itself it just moves to the mouse's location. So my question is how can I force the context menu to close to it can update the bool I am using to keep track of its open state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can close the context menu manually:

```
contextMenu.DropDown.ClosePopup();
```